# Centre of mass of a solid.

Tags: calculus

The shape is a result of rotating this area(The area below the curve in the image) around a z-axis (north) by 90 degrees.
[image]

(Not resulting in a quarter of a hemisphere, but a quarter of a cylinder with a quarter-hemisphere cored out, sorry, my terminology is terrible)

I have found its volume to be

$V = \pi a^3/3$ and

and it's z coordinate centre of mass to be $a/4$.

I am having trouble finding the x coordinate centre of mass. The x axis being the one pointing east in the diagram.

I have deduced an equation relating z to a and x.

$$(a-z)^2 + x^2 = a^2$$

Where I have taken the origin to be the centre of the would be sphere.

I have attempted to work with circles at height $z = a/4$ and found $x=\sqrt{7}/4$

Comment: I cannot understand where is the Z-axis in your image, can you clarify a bit?

Comment: The thick line on the left. Sorry, I can see that it isnt clear now.

Comment: Why is the picture upside down?

Comment: I graphed $\sqrt{x^2-4}$, but needed.... the up;side down one.

Comment: I could not think of a function that traced the outline of a semicircle.